# Como ciclo for o while, interacion ejemplo (1)(1+2)(1+2+3)(1+2+3+4)...n hasta 100

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, while

Elabora un programa en el que utilices el ciclo for o el ciclo while para encontrar la suma de una serie, el código se detendrá cuando el resultado de la suma sea menor o igual a al valor de 100.
Ejemplo de la serie: (1)+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+…+(1+2+3+…+n)<=100
Escribe el resultado de cada una de las iteraciones, hasta que la condición se cumpla.
Iteracion1=1
Iteracion2=3
….
IteracionN=n

```
var serie=0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    serie += i;
     console.log('Interacion: ' + i + ' : ' + serie);  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var serie = 1;

for (var i = 2; serie <= 100; i++)
{
    console.log('Interación: ' + i + ' : ' + serie);  
    serie += i;
}
```

El **ciclo for** consta de tres partes:

Inicialización de la variable: **var i = 0**

Condición: **i <= 100**

Incremento de la variable por la que se itera: **i++**

Estas partes pueden omitirse o no en dependencia de tus necesidades, así como inicializar a la vez varias variables, poner múltiples condiciones e incrementar varias variables.

En tu **ciclo for** en vez de poner **i <= 100**, pon **serie <= 100** de esta forma lograrás el resultado esperado.

O bien puedes resumirlo de esta forma:

```
for (var i = 2, serie = 1; serie <= 100; i++)
{
   console.log('Interación: ' + i + ' : ' + serie);  
   serie += i;
}
```

De esta forma el código es más corto ya que eliminas la declaración de la **variable serie** ya que la declaras dentro de las partes del **ciclo for**.

Y si quieres resumirlo más pues pon esto:

```
for (var i = 1, serie = 1; serie <= 100; i++, serie += i)
{
   console.log('Interación: ' + i + ' : ' + serie);       
}
```

La **variable serie** también se incrementa dentro de una de las partes del **ciclo for**.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! ¡Tu explicar muy sencillo! ¡Gracias por ayudarme! Estaba difícil mi código je, je, je